# Standard input problem with typescript node

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, stdin

I needed to create a script that takes from the standard input, and waits until it does not get the user input, and then goes on according to what the user did. This is the code I have written so far:

```
    let userInput: string | null = null;
    let standard_in: any = process.stdin;

    standard_in.setRawMode(true);
    standard_in.setEncoding('utf8');
    standard_in.resume();

    process.stdout.write("Welcome to CodeWhisperer code generator\n");
    
    do {
        // some logic to put into a variable some values
        process.stdout.write("This is the command you asked for:\n");
        // display the value
        process.stdout.write("Do you want to use it? (y/n)\n");
        // Get response from the user
        standard_in.on("data", (data: any) => {
            console.log("HERERER")
            userInput = data.toString().trim();
        })

        while (userInput === null) {
            // Wait for user input
        }

        console.log(userInput)
        if (userInput === 'y') {
            process.stdout.write("Great! Let's go!\n");
            interactive = false;
        }
    } while(interactive);
```

But if I do like this, it hangs forever, and nothing happens.
If I remove the inner `while`, the code ends whithout waiting for the user input, and I cannot read it. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```typescript
let userInput: string | null = null;
let standard_in: any = process.stdin;

standard_in.setRawMode(true);
standard_in.setEncoding('utf8');
standard_in.resume();

process.stdout.write("Welcome to CodeWhisperer code generator\n");

function getUserInput(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        standard_in.on("data", (data: any) => {
            userInput = data.toString().trim();
            resolve(userInput);
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    do {
        // some logic to put into a variable some values
        process.stdout.write("This is the command you asked for:\n");
        // display the value
        process.stdout.write("Do you want to use it? (y/n)\n");

        userInput = await getUserInput();

        console.log(userInput);

        if (userInput === 'y') {
            process.stdout.write("Great! Let's go!\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (true);

    // Add the rest of your code here, if needed
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let userInput: string | null = null;
let standard_in: any = process.stdin;

 standard_in.setRawMode(true);
 standard_in.setEncoding('utf8');
 standard_in.resume();

 process.stdout.write("Welcome to CodeWhisperer code generator\n");

 function processUserInput(data: any) {
   console.log("HERERER");
   userInput = data.toString().trim();

   if (userInput === 'y') {
     process.stdout.write("Great! Let's go!\n");
     standard_in.removeListener("data", processUserInput); // Remove the       
     listener after getting the user input
     // Put any other logic you want to execute after getting 'y' from 
     the user.
         }
      }

     standard_in.on("data", processUserInput);
```

Comment: No, it still terminates the execution without waiting for the user input